# Spying on selfinjecting bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to spy on a bean, that injects itself?

Suppose we have

```
@Service
public class SomeClass {
    @Autowired
    private SomeClass someClass;
    ...
}
```

Now I want to use the following in my test:

```
@SpyBean
private SomeClass someClass;
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Bean with name 'someClass' has been injected into other beans [someClass] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.

Also without self injection tests run flawlessly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you injecting the same Bean type? Especially being this is a singleton.

Comment: @LppEdd for the `@Transactional` to work. When invoked on the method of the same class it must be proxied (must be a bean) to be transactional.

Comment: Maybe the AspectJ integration with runtime/compile time weaving is a better solution

Comment: Application is already written in spring, I don't want to change it;<

Comment: You don't have, the Spring AOP module supports AspectJ weaving. You'd just have to add a compilation step, or add a Java Agent. I say this because yours seems like a hack

Comment: @LppEdd why hack? Self-injection and circular dependencies are supported by spring

Comment: Why would you have to self-inject instead of directly calling a class method? That's why I say this isn't an optimal solution